# List Box User Form for multiple inputs into single cell

Tags: string, vba, excel

Can someone please help me with an issue? The new requirement was for a combobox to be replaced by a listbox that will allow multiple selections and entered into a single cell. The one I am speaking about is the Me.Reason_RRT_Called Any help would be greatly appriciated. The code is below.

```
            Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ssheet As Workbook
    Dim cellVal1 As String, cellVal2 As String, cellVal3 As String, cellVal4 As String
    Dim cellVal5 As String, cellVal6 As String, cellVal7 As String, cellVal8 As String
    Dim cellVal9 As String, cellVal10 As String, cellVal11 As String, cellVal12 As String
    Dim cellVal13 As String, cellVal14 As String

    Dim shtCmb As String
    Dim RwLast As Long
    Dim Reasons As String
    Dim n As Integer

    shtCmb = Me.Year.Value
        If shtCmb = "" Then
             MsgBox "Please choose a Year.", vbOKOnly
             Me.Year.SetFocus
    End If
         For n = 0 To Reason_RRT_Called.ListCount - 1
             If Reason_RRT_Called.Selected(n) = True Then
                Reasons = Reasons & Reason_RRT_Called.List(n) & "; "
             End If
         Next n

    cellVal1 = Me.Year.Text
    cellVal2 = Reasons
    cellVal3 = Me.Type_Of_Recomendations.Text
    cellVal4 = Me.Documentation_On_Templates.Text
    cellVal5 = Me.MD_Notified.Text
    cellVal6 = Me.Location.Text
    cellVal7 = Me.Code_Rapid_Response.Text
    cellVal8 = Me.Report_Sent_To_QM.Text
    cellVal9 = Me.Vital_Signs_Documneted.Text
    cellVal10 = Me.Assessments_Completed.Text
    cellVal11 = Me.Response_Time.Text
    cellVal12 = Me.Date_Of_Incedent.Text
    cellVal13 = Me.Patients_Name.Text
    cellVal14 = Me.Unit_Location.Text

    RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("H" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal2
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("K" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal3
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("L" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal4
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("N" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal5
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("E" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal6
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("D" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal7
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("G" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal8
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("I" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal9
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("J" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal10
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("M" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal11
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("A" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal12
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("C" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal13
    Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("F" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal14

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Private Sub optionCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant

    'Auto date fill text box
    'Date_Of_Incedent.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

      'Year(Year(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Year
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = Year Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.Year
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = Year
    End With

    'fill the listBox
    With Me.Reason_RRT_Called
        For Each Entry In [List2]
          .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With


       'fill the combo box
    With Me.Type_Of_Recomendations
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

           'fill the combo box
    With Me.Documentation_On_Templates
        For Each Entry In [List4]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

              'fill the combo box
    With Me.MD_Notified
        For Each Entry In [List5]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

        'fill the combo box
    With Me.Location
        For Each Entry In [List6]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.Code_Rapid_Response
        For Each Entry In [List7]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.Report_Sent_To_QM
        For Each Entry In [List8]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.Vital_Signs_Documneted
        For Each Entry In [List9]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

 'fill the combo box
    With Me.Assessments_Completed
        For Each Entry In [List10]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

  'fill the combo box
    With Me.Response_Time
        For Each Entry In [List11]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a drop down list for a cell I use data validation. In order to create a drop down list using VBA, Use the following lines of code:

```
With range("A1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=B1:B6"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Instead of "A1" put the cell you want the drop down list to appear in.
Instead of "=B1:B6"  put the range to get the data from.

Comment: Do I replace this 'fill the listBox
    With Me.Reason_RRT_Called
        For Each Entry In [List2]
          .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With With the code that you posted of corse changing the cell references. Also this will be going in as multiple entries and depending on the year it will go into several different worksheets.

Comment: To understand how this code works, on cells B1 to B6 print the number 1~6. Copy the code in the Sheet1 visual basic editor and run it. Then click on cells A1. You will see a drop down list

Comment: Okay tried the code and it works like you said but not really what I need. I need to be able to select multiple items i.e. 2,4,6 and be able to save in a single cell. This list box is located on a userform and the employee will be able to check each box that goes into that cell from the user form.

Comment: Please go to the link I've mentioned on the post, there is a part regrading drop down lists on forms and how to populate them with data

Comment: Read the info on the website and it is refering to drop down lists. Thats not what I am looking for. I need a listbox that will allow you to select 3 or 4 items at once to put into 1 cell.

Comment: loop through all the list box items. If ListBox1.Selected(i) = true then you now that item is selected.

Comment: What should my variable (i) represent? Do I need to declair it to i=0 and then have another variable like J=1???

Comment: your variable i will loop through the items in the list box

Comment: Step1: you must loop through the items in your list box and determine the indices that are selected. Step 2: Populate any column with the data from the list box. Step3: Create a Data validation. If you are still having trouble with the file please send me an email and I will take a look at your file

Comment: I have fixed it. The code works perfect now. Thanks for your help and a friend of mine. together it has been fixed and working great.